# Set up a Maven Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, github

I got problems when I try to "connect" (not sure if this is the right word).
I git cloned the repository from GitHub and then I imported the existing Maven Project, selected the pom and pressed next and at the end finish then I right-clicked on my project and choose "Share Project" and selected Git, there we go after that I stucked to this window you see in the screenshot....

[image: Error when sharing Project with Team]

Comment: Your project came from that Git repository, so it is **already shared**. Resharing it would put a folder with a `.project` file, which indicates that it's a project, underneath one that's already there.

Comment: so whats the solution to this? Because if I change something in that project, I can't push it to the GitHub..... should I delete the .project file?

Comment: What do you mean by, "can't push it to the GutHub"? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to this problem was: to click on the checkbox: "use or create repository in parent folder of project" on the screenshot and then just press finish